# Disabling su access for all new users on Debian

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sudo

I'm new to Debian, but learning things very fast.

Working on Debian Wheezy, and I realize that if I create a new user with useradd, the user gets sudo rights! To test this, I log in with the new user through ssh, and I find that the user can sudo, and it prompts for root's password, and as the new user enters the root password, the user gets root access!

When I run `more /etc/group`, the sudo group only has one original user that I created while installing Debian to have sudo rights so that I don't have to log in through root for security.

But to my surprise, every new user created, even though not added to sudo group, is getting the right to sudo. Why is this happening? Anyway, my `/etc/sudoers` file has the following lines uncommented :

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I'm suspecting the last line to be responsible for this. Is it due to the same? How I can stop every new user from getting the right to sudo? Thanks.

Comment: I would delete and/or comment the line out and see if anything changes.

Comment: the new user's name is aa,now if I do id aa, I get this:
uid=1001(aa) gid=1001(aa) groups=1001(aa)

Comment: Rambound, but that came out of the box! Seems a default setting... and nowhere its mentioned with deb that this would happen with new users... I'm even logged into my new deb vps on ec2, the same scenario there, even though the /etc/sudoers file is blank!

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing su and sudo? You make a reference to the root password, but sudo uses the USERS password to elevate to root - if she is in the sudoers...

Comment: Oh! Yes, I'm sorry,, never knew sudo and su are different,, yes I checked, I was doing su with the new users, and once I enter root's pwd, I gain root access! So, is that how it's made to function? But I need to block users from able to su/sudo both. How can I do that? Should I change the title of this post? Thanks Mattias. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: What if something running on the system could brute force su and get the root access only because the user under which its running has the right to su?

Comment: SU is working exactly as intended.  It is meant to allow you to escalate your privileges on a local box - IF you know the root users password.   If you don't want people to be able to log in as root, don't let them know this password !   If something is running on the system and you trust them that little you have bigger problems.

Comment: Davidgo, I believe in resolving the problem before it arises... As users on linux doesn't mean a real human, can be a package, can be a script or a worm getting inside and running under that user... I learnt you can't blindly trust the user and need to restrict that user as much as possible to the extent you want to assign privileges   to that user.. Want to harden my instance to max possible extent.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pam_wheel to disable su access for users not in the wheel group. This requires you to add a wheel group using `addgroup --system wheel`.

Then, add users who should have access to su to the wheel group using `usermod -a -G wheel user`.

Finally, add the following line to /etc/pam.d/su: `auth requisite pam_wheel.so group=wheel`.

Comment: Thanks for this info 67, am new to linux, will learn PAM management soon.

Comment: If you want to completely disable `su`, you can skip adding a `wheel` group to your operating system. Just keep in mind that you need either to be in the `sudoers` group (and have a properly configured / default `sudo` installation) or you need to have physical access to the machine in order not to be locked out for administrative tasks.